# Is there a way to stop previous day's values from being recalculated after new data comes through on the current day

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

My Excel formula depends on data I receive from a website every morning. My problem is, when new data comes, data from previous day recalculates & affects current day's value as it is also dependent on the previous day value. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You'd probably need a macro to do this rather than a formula. I believe that with formulas the value is not saved and so it is calculated each time the sheet is opened or refreshed. A macro could write the values themselves and so they would not get overwritten.

Comment: Also, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: This question would benefit from the addition of some sample data as well as formulas so we know what you are doing and the impact.

Comment: Create the macro copy and paste the previous day value to a new worksheet, and run the formula depend on the new Workbook data .